# Why is `datetime.date.today` slower than `datetime.datetime.now` in Python?

Tags: python

Out of curiosity, I did the following benchmark of these two functions:

```
In [12]: %timeit datetime.datetime.now()
100000 loops, best of 3: 5.09 µs per loop

In [13]: %timeit datetime.date.today()
100000 loops, best of 3: 6.4 µs per loop
```

I thought `date` object involved less information, so it should be the faster one, but it turned out to be slower.

What could be the reason?

Comment: Maybe take a look the at the source code of [`now`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/070fed5b7b9d/Lib/datetime.py#l1394) and [`today`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/070fed5b7b9d/Lib/datetime.py#l679).

Comment: interestingly utcnow is even faster then now and today...

Comment: datetime module is compiled C so i cant easily check it.   Without looking at the code,  I would suspect that "today" might use "now" and then parse off the date.   Same call to hardware to get the date and time then some processing to give the correct result.

Answer (score 1):

I got nerd-sniped by this today so I'll show you what I found -- strap in.

first, the implementation of `date.today()` must go through a member function call -- this lookup appears to be the slow part:

https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/b2bf2bc1ece673d387341e06c8d3c2bc6e259747/Modules/_datetimemodule.c#L2886-L2892

excerpted here:

```c
static PyObject *
date_today(PyObject *cls, PyObject *dummy)
{
    PyObject *time;
    PyObject *result;
    _Py_IDENTIFIER(fromtimestamp);

    time = time_time();
    if (time == NULL)
        return NULL;

    /* Note well:  today() is a class method, so this may not call
     * date.fromtimestamp.  For example, it may call
     * datetime.fromtimestamp.  That's why we need all the accuracy
     * time.time() delivers; if someone were gonzo about optimization,
     * date.today() could get away with plain C time().
     */
    result = _PyObject_CallMethodIdOneArg(cls, &PyId_fromtimestamp, time);
    Py_DECREF(time);
    return result;
}
```

notably it's *always* going through the slow path

so I figured, why not give it a fast path?

```
$ git diff -w
diff --git a/Modules/_datetimemodule.c b/Modules/_datetimemodule.c
index 8ef2dad37a..7eaa5d1740 100644
--- a/Modules/_datetimemodule.c
+++ b/Modules/_datetimemodule.c
@@ -2875,6 +2875,17 @@ date_fromtimestamp(PyObject *cls, PyObject *obj)
 static PyObject *
 date_today(PyObject *cls, PyObject *dummy)
 {
+    /* fast path, don't call fromtimestamp */
+    if ((PyTypeObject *)cls == &PyDateTime_DateType) {
+        struct tm tm;
+        time_t t;
+        time(&t);
+        localtime_r(&t, &tm);
+        return new_date_ex(tm.tm_year + 1900,
+                           tm.tm_mon + 1,
+                           tm.tm_mday,
+                           (PyTypeObject*)cls);
+    } else {
         PyObject *time;
         PyObject *result;
         _Py_IDENTIFIER(fromtimestamp);
@@ -2893,6 +2904,7 @@ date_today(PyObject *cls, PyObject *dummy)
         Py_DECREF(time);
         return result;
     }
+}
 
 /*[clinic input]
 @classmethod
```

zoom zoom

```
$ ./python -m timeit -s 'from datetime import date' 'date.today()'
500000 loops, best of 5: 407 nsec per loop
$ ./python -m timeit -s 'from datetime import datetime' 'datetime.now().date()'
500000 loops, best of 5: 764 nsec per loop
```

Answer (score -2):

I think `datetime.datetime.today()` is a part of or it calls `datetime.datetime.now()`. I'm not sure though. Extracting "today" from "now" takes extra time. It also depends on hardware and the time at which the process was called. Did you take many readings and average it or it's constantly the same delay ?

Comment: No, it doesn't call `now`, at least for the Python implementation of the module.

Comment: the interesting thing is that now seem to do all that today does and some more on top of that (python wise)